# Безопасно ли хранить пароль и логин в js?

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular

Есть общий 'login-layout' компонент который роутит другие компоненты :

```
<div class="login">
  <div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="message!=null || isConfirmed" class="success-message">
      <span *ngIf="message!=null">{{message}}</span>
      <span *ngIf="isConfirmed">Вы успешно активировали почту! Можете авторизоваться</span>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

И есть два компонента : 1) форма заполнения пароля и логина, 2) выбор организации

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'form'
      },
      {
        path: 'form', component: LoginFormComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'organizations', component: OrganizationSelectedComponent,
      }]
  },
];
```

Когда я отправляю логин и пароль с компонента loginForm, на сервере проверяю логин и пароль и получаю список организации в которой он зареган, На сервер  повторно отправляю : {login,password,idOrganization},
Получается что в компоненте organizationSelected я  должен знать логин и пароль. 
У меня есть 2 идеи реализовать это, но у них есть минусы:
1) я должен вместо router-outlet вставлять селекторы и через ngif отображать компоненты.
2) я должен создать какой нибудь сервис для обмена данными:

```
export class LoginDataService {
  private data = new BehaviorSubject<AuthModel>(new AuthModel());
  private data$ = this.data.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setData(data: AuthModel) {
    this.data.next(data);
  }

  getData(): Observable<AuthModel> {
    return this.data$;
  }
}
```

и через router-outlet можно будет генерить компоненты . 
Является ли 2 - идея безопасным? И какой лучше использовать? Или предложите свои идеи

Comment: А зачем хранить логин и пароль? Почему бы не хранить куку?

Comment: @iluxa1810 ,  чтобы авторизоваться.  В куках - я думаю это плохая идея

Comment: Ну пользователь 1 раз отсылает свои учетные данные, а сервер ему возвращает токен. Так вот, при последующих запросах юзер шлет этот токен.

Comment: @iluxa1810 , вопрос не про токен, а про правильной передаче логина и пароля в другой компонент.

Comment: @АнуарТемирбулат правильным ответом как раз и является ответ про токен

Comment: @АнуарТемирбулат, опишите способ авторизации на бэке. Отсюда станет понятно, как Вам лучше помочь.

Answer (score 0):

я и так храню токен на клиенте и с каждым запросом отправляю в хедере. Мой метод контроллера авторизации:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Transactional]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] AuthenticationRequest request,
            [FromServices] IAuthenticationManager authentication)
        {
            var jwt = await authentication.AuthenticateWithRefreshAsync(request.Login, request.Password, request.OrganizationBin);
            if (jwt == null)
            {
                return Ok(ApiResponse.Failed(ApiErrorCode.AuthenticationFailed, "Неверный логин\\пароль"));
            }
            return Ok(ApiResponse.Success(jwt));
        }
```

Модель :

```
public class AuthenticationRequest {
        [Required]
        public string Login { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string OrganizationBin { get; set; }
    }
```

Вот код который в хедер вписывает токен:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(
    public auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }  
}
```